# add javascript code in knitr

Tags: javascript, r, knitr

How do I add javascript code to a `Rmd`?

I'm using the following chunk options:

````
```{r engine = 'js', results='asis', echo = T, highlight = T}
var i = 1 + 1;
```
````

And this produces a `.md` with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1 + 1;
</script>
```

I would like to have something like:

````
```js
var i = 1 + 1;
```

<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1 + 1;
</script>
````

In other words, I don't need the code to be evaluated when knitting, I just need that highlighted code appears in the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of [**knitr** v1.16.5](https://github.com/yihui/knitr), this is the default behavior, i.e. the JS code will be echoed by default. This will work out of the box:

````
```{js}
var i = 1 + 1;
```
````

Comment: `js` option does not appear on latest RStudio code chunk options. Works when manually added though.

Comment: I can make an HTML document and link css `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">` but JavaScript does not seem to work? `<script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>`